# JSLint: used out of scope for ternary variable set

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, jslint

I have a code block like this:

```
/*global MYAPP: true*/
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};
```

JSLint highlights "MYAPP" after equal sign with message "MYAPP used out of scope".

What's wrong with that?

Comment: `var MYAPP = window.MYAPP || {};`, otherwise the expression always leaves `MYAPP` as `{}` because 'MYAPP' will be `undefined` owing to the var hoisting.

Comment: Actually it works but JSLint.

Comment: But what we will use in node.js? There is no `window`.

Comment: I've found another way: 
`var MYAPP;
MYAPP = MYAPP || {};`

Comment: hmm. i guess you need a temporary variable with a different name, i didn't realize that before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `var` then you are declaring a local variable.
If you do `MYAPP || {}` then you are typically trying to set a default value for a global variable, or for a variable declared earlier.

What is the scope of `MYAPP` supposed to be?  If it is global, then something like

```
MYAPP = window.MYAPP || {};
```

`window.` stops it from complaining that it is undefined

If it is not global but declared earlier, then

```
MYAPP = MYAPP || {};
```

If it is a new variable local to the function that this line is part of then

```
var MYAPP = {};
```

If you have a variable defined at the top level of your script (i.e. not in a function), then it is a global.  If you have global variables in two different script tags (or javascript files) with the same name, then they are the same variable.
If you want to hide a variable from other script tags (or javascript files), consider using an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression).  e.g.

```
(function() {
    var MYAPP = {};
    //code that uses MYAPP;
})();
//MYAPP is not visible out here, or in other script tags/files.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what you think about `var MYAPP; MYAPP = MYAPP || {};`?

Comment: The `MYAPP || ` part is not necessary, because if you do var MYAPP, that is declaring a new variable called `MYAPP`.  

If you had anything else called `MYAPP`, then that is a different variable, because you used `var`.

There would be no difference in the end result between `var MYAPP; MYAPP = MYAPP || {};` and `var MYAPP = {};`

Comment: Yeah, I thought like you. :) But try to test:
`<script>
    var MY = MY || {aa:'aa'};
</script>
<script>
    var MY;
    MY = MY || {aa:'bb'};
    console.log(MY.aa);
</script>`

Comment: What's happened there is that they are both in the same scope, so it is only one var.  Top level variables (i.e. not inside a function) are globals in javascript, and can collide with eachother.  So, even though they're in separate script tags, they are still the same global variable.  If you want to make them only visible to the script tags containing them, then consider using an IIFE e.g.
`<script>(function() {var MY = MY || {aa:'aa'}; /*other code*/})();</script>`

Answer (score 1):

For jshint, jslint, sonarqube, etc. no variables could be used without is explicitly declared with `var` (`let` or `const`).

If you want set them global, you must in first time defined what is the current global keyword because it's `window` into browser but in other context, maybe it's not that !

So see below how to avoid your warning (JSDoc Comment are not part of solution but explained why is usefull).

```
/**
 * @fileOverview Starting point for Front-end [Your Project Name]'s JavaScript.
 * @author {@link http://www.lesieur.name/|Bruno Lesieur}
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @module Common
 * @requires {@link external:jQuery}
 */

var window = this,

    /**
     * Container for all function of website.
     * @namespace website
     * @global
     * @type {Object}
     */
    website = window.website || {},

    /**
     * Write less, Do more.
     * @external jQuery
     * @global
     * @see {@link https://jquery.com/|jQuery}
     */
    $ = window.$,

    /**
     * Shortcut for $(window).
     * @global
     * @type {jQuery}
     */
    $window = window.$window || $(window);

/**
 * All components (modules) avaiable on all pages.
 * @namespace components
 * @alias components
 * @type {Object}
 * @memberOf website.
 */
website.components = website.components || {};
```

So in your example the easy way it's :

```
var window = this,
    MYAPP = window.MYAPP || {};
```

or

```
var global = this,
    MYAPP = global.MYAPP || {};
```

or

```
var MYAPP = this.MYAPP || {};
```